# Where to save different models at once in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I have a litte question for you.

I'm using Laravel and I'm not sure which is the best way (and place) to save different models at same time.

For example:

When a user creates a "RecordSheet", I need to automatically create other models related to the RecordSheet model. Obviously I will create the RecordSheet model in his own controller:

```
class RecordSheetController extends Controller
{
   public function store(){
    RecordSheet::create([
    .......
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);
   }
}
```

Where should I put the creation of the other models? In the same RecordSheetController?

```
class RecordSheetController extends Controller
{
  public function store(){
    DB:beginTranaction()
    
    try{
    $record = RecordSheet::create([
    .......
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);

    ModelB::create([
    .......
    'recordSheet' => $record->id,
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);

    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
      DB:rollback();
    }
    DB:committ();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure about thate since I suppose that RecordSheetController should be responsible only of "RecordSheet" models and not other models.

Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Laravel Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers) for this scenario, create a `RecordSheetObserver` and place your `ModelB` code in the `created` method

Comment: Hi Mahmoud and thank you for your answer. I thought about the observer but using it I won't be able to use a transaction, am I right?

Comment: You will be able to use `Database Transactions` here is an example

`DB::transaction(function () {

   $record = RecordSheet::create([
    .......
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);

});
`

Comment: Yes but that transaction will work only on the controller and not in the observer. I need that if a "RecordSheet" is created then a "ModelB" must be created. I need that both are created. If one fails, both fails and the user will be prompted with the error. If I use the observer pattern, it will be triggered only after the "RecordSheet" creation. Then for some reason the "ModelB" creation triggered by the observer can fail and I will be left with a "RecordSheet" without a "modelB".

Comment: The whole transaction will revert if the modelB didn't created, you can try it.

Comment: Well you're right! I wasn't doubting you I just didn't know that the event in the observer was part of the transaction. Thank you, I will use this method where I have to save more than 2 models at same time. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides some built-in conventions for placement of your action or CRUD (Create - Read - Update - Delete) code.

Typically, you can put the related model action in the same method.  To start, you can utilise the artisan command:

```
php artisan make:controller RecordSheetController --resource
```

This will add the standard methods to your controller.  These methods tie into any `resource` methods you have in your routing, which follow standards for GET/POST/PUT/etc.

Once you have your controller set up, it is usually easiest and most readable to do your related action within the same method, so you don't have to go back and forth with the user from page to controller and back again.  So:

```
public function store(Request $request){ 
    // Add transactions as you wish
    $record = RecordSheet::create([
     .......
    ' user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);

    ModelB::create([
    .......
    'recordSheet' => $record->id,
   'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
   ]);
}
```

You can certainly make sub functions within this, but the key is to perform this at one time for efficiency.  If there are many repeatable sub functions with less related actions, it may be helpful to move this to other parts of your app.  But for simple, directly related creation, it tends to be more readable to keep them in the same class.

Comment: Hi Watercayman and thank you for your answer. In my question I totally forgot to write the function i'm using. I'm using the "store()" function created with the --resource flag as you suggested. I'll update my question.
Beyond that, your suggestion is to leave both model creations on the same controller even if the controller is not directly responsible of the ModelB?

Comment: No worries.  And yes, that is exactly my suggestion.  Keep the action close when it is a direct consequence of another creation/edit.  But this is just a suggestion, it may come down to preference if the models are less related or more 'distant' depending on how you wish to architect your code.  Consistency is important.  Readability for me is most important - separating code to different areas for direct consequence creations is less readable / less efficient than having it right in front of you, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you again. I will probably proceed this way then. It is the pattern I followed until this moment but then I asked myself if I was doing right since I thought about the "single responsibility" pattern. Thank you!